# Trying to pass props down to child component/route but ".children" is returning null

Tags: react-router

I made comments in the code. I tried to make it as straightforward as possible. For some reason ".children" is returning "null" inside "Index.js" or CompetitionsIndex component, it should not do this because ViewCompetition component is the child as seen in "routes.js"

```js
// routes.js

<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route   path='/'                        component={Main} >
      <IndexRoute                            component={Home} />
      <Route path="login"                    component={Login} />
      <Route path="logout"                   component={Logout} />
      <Route path="register"                 component={Register} />
      <Route path="CompetitionIndex"         component={CompetitionIndex} >
        <Route path="/ViewCompetition/:id"   component={ViewCompetition} />
   </Route>
      <Route path="CreateCompetition"        component={CreateCompetition} />
      <Route path="EditCompetition/:id"      component={EditCompetition} />
      <Route path="dashboard"                component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Router>

// Main.js

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      userRole: null
    }
  }

  // ... methods and stuff
 
  render() {
    let childrenWithProps = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {userRole: this.state.userRole});

    return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {childrenWithProps}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

// Dashboard.js

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let userRole = this.props.userRole // Works Like a charm!!!

    return(
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <p> DASHBOARD (A Secure Route)</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


// Everything above works great! 
// Now check out the same exact pattern below
// I'm trying to pass props(editableDoc) from CompetitionIndex to it's child component/route ViewCompetition
// The same EXACT way I passed props(userRole) from Main to it's child component/route dashboard


// Index.js

export default class CompetitionIndex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      error: false,
      docList: [],
      editableDoc: []
    }
  }

  handleView(docId) {
    db.get(docId).then((doc) => {

      this.setState({
        editableDoc: doc
      })
      this.context.router.push(`/ViewCompetition/${doc._id}`)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      this.setState({
        error: err
      })
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
 // some code
  }

  render() {
    let FML = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {editableDoc: this.state.editableDoc});

    return(
        <div>{FML}</div>
    )
  }
}

// Before even getting to render() the View.js below I get this shitty Error
// bundle.js:967 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
// After console logging a bunch I realize everything is ok until I call `.children`, so there's no children?
// How da puck is that possible When I'm doing the EXACT same thing with Main and dashboard...???


// View.js

export default class ViewCompetition extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("editableDocument", this.props.editableDoc)
    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an `<IndexRoute component={whatever} />` inside of `<Route component={CompetitionIndex} >`

This enabled me to pass props down from "CompetitionIndex" to "ViewCompetition"

Why this fixes the problem I'm not exactly sure. All I can think of is if you're nesting routes each level has to have an `<IndexRoute/>` if you want to pass props down from the parent.